# Run exe inside windows docker container

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am unable to run a windows exe file inside docker. I have tried both with CMD ["test.exe"], and from the interactive mode. In all cases the exe terminates immediately without any error messages and that makes it difficult to debug. Has anyone experienced anything similar? Can it be a dll issue? The exe runs perfectly on the host Win 10 system. The image used is windowsservercore

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar issue trying to run an exe inside a windowsservercore-based container and like you suspect in your case, the problem was related to dlls not being present. I used [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to identify which dlls my process loads at start-up and then ensured that all those dlls are available inside the container. In my case it was a Visual C++ 2015 redistributable that needed to be installed inside the container while building the image.

Comment: You run procmon on your regular non-docker environment and figure out what is loaded at startup. Then you ensure that the same is made available in your docker container by modifying the Dockerfile appropriately.

Comment: Can you please explain how you used procmon? the documentation is poor. I have installed it but I can't see how I would get the required information

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this. A few tips to help to track down the problem. Does it still happen if you use a [full Windows image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows) or even a [smaller Servercore image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore)?

Next thing to try is to install the dotnet core runtime (and possibly also the aspnet core runtime) in a Servercore image as recommended [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1741571/83636). Here's some sample code I wrote to achieve this based on that answer but using more recent versions. Note that uses Chocolatey to install the dotnetcore. You might have DNS issues downloading Chocolatey which you can resolve with your Docker Desktop or daemon.json dns config. You can check the latest versions of those Chocolatey distributions [here](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/dotnetcore-runtime):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
ARG DOTNET_CORE_RUNTIME 3.1.32
RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; \
  [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; \
  iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1')); \
  choco install dotnetcore-runtime --version=${DOTNET_CORE_RUNTIME} -y;  \
  choco install aspnetcore-runtimepackagestore --version ${DOTNET_CORE_RUNTIME} -y
```

Finally, if you're still stuck you could try a tool like [Dependency Walker](https://dependencywalker.com/) to see what dependencies your application actually uses, and then try to install those.